# rotate 5 circle problem

Tags: c, opengl, 3d, rotation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to rotate this openGl code…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233589/how-to-rotate-this-opengl-code)

below is my code and it work fine.. i draw 5 ring in this.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>

static void redraw(void);
#define PI 3.14159265 
#define EDGES 90
#define factor 10


void display (void) 
{
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);
     glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();   


//ring1 
glPushMatrix();
glColor3f (0.0, 0.0 ,1.0);
glTranslatef(-30.0,10.0,-100.0);
redraw();
glutSwapBuffers();
glPopMatrix();

//ring2
glPushMatrix();
glColor3f (0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glTranslatef(-8.0,10.0,-100.0);
redraw();
glutSwapBuffers();
glPopMatrix();

//ring3
glPushMatrix();
glColor3f (1.0, 0.0 ,0.0);
glTranslatef(14.0,10.0,-100.0);
redraw();
glutSwapBuffers();
glPopMatrix();

//ring4
glPushMatrix();
glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glTranslatef(-19.0,-2.0,-100.0);
redraw();
glutSwapBuffers();
glPopMatrix();

//ring5
glPushMatrix();
glColor3f (0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glTranslatef(4.0,-2.0,-100.0);
redraw();
glutSwapBuffers();
glPopMatrix();

}

static void redraw(void)
{
for (int i = 0; i < EDGES; i++)
    { 
      glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP); 
      glVertex2f(factor*cos((2*PI*i)/EDGES),factor*sin((2*PI*i)/EDGES)); 
      glVertex2f(factor*cos((2*PI*(i+1))/EDGES),factor*sin((2*PI*(i+1))/EDGES)); 
      glEnd();
     } 
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
glutInit(&argc,argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
glutInitWindowSize(110*3, 110*3);
glutCreateWindow("draw circle");
glPointSize(3); 
glShadeModel (GL_FLAT); 
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);    
gluPerspective(45,1.0,10.0,200.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glutMainLoop();
return 0; 
}
```

so i want to rotate all of this circle.. how can i do??

Comment: Please always use forward slashes as directory separators -- it works on all platforms!

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you want. How do you want to rotate them?

Comment: If you rotate a circle it's still a circle - maybe you can explain more clearly what it is that you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: i want to rotate them on z-axis ....

Comment: genpfault  how to rotate this openGl....  this is my pos but i want to rotate in z-axis..

Comment: You want to rotate about z-axis and have tagged it as 2d? May be I am missing something here ...

Comment: @genpfault I didn't know someone else already solved exactly the same problem. Now I feel a bit stupid. I demand the "Badge of Useless Work"!

Comment: @logic_max Do not be too sensitive ;) i forgot to edit this

Comment: @hesam : I am not that sensitive :). I didn't down-vote :P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call glutSwapBuffers only once in the drawing function.

For an animation you have to call glutPostRedisplay, to ensure that the display function will be called again.

The glBegin and glEnd calls only have to be called once per circle. In the for loop you just supply vertices with calls to glVertex.

To simplify debugging I installed a keyboard handler that closes the window when the escape key is pressed.

```
 // compile in linux: gcc ogl.c -lglut -lGLU

#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void redraw(void);
#define PI 3.14159265 

enum{
  EDGES=90,
};

static void 
circle(float radius)
{
  int i;
  glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP); 
  for (i = 0; i < EDGES; i++){ 
    glVertex2f(radius*cos((2*PI*i)/EDGES),
           radius*sin((2*PI*i)/EDGES)); 
    glVertex2f(radius*cos((2*PI*(i+1))/EDGES),
           radius*sin((2*PI*(i+1))/EDGES)); 
  } 
  glEnd();
}


int count=0;
void display (void) 
{
  float r=10;
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glLoadIdentity();   

  glRotated(count,0,0,1);
  count++;
  if(count>360)
    count=0;

  glPushMatrix();
  // ring1
  glColor3f (0.0, 0.0 ,1.0);
  glTranslatef(-30.0,10.0,-100.0);
  circle(r);
  glPopMatrix();

  glPushMatrix();
  // ring2
  glColor3f (0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glTranslatef(-8.0,10.0,-100.0);
  circle(r);
  glPopMatrix();

  glPushMatrix();
  //ring3
  glColor3f (1.0, 0.0 ,0.0);
  glTranslatef(14.0,10.0,-100.0);
  circle(r);
  glPopMatrix();

  glPushMatrix();
  //ring4
  glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  glTranslatef(-19.0,-2.0,-100.0);
  circle(r);
  glPopMatrix();

  glPushMatrix();
  //ring5
  glColor3f (0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  glTranslatef(4.0,-2.0,-100.0);
  circle(r);
  glPopMatrix();

  glutSwapBuffers();
  glutPostRedisplay();
}

static void 
keyb(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
  switch (key) {
  case 27:  /* Escape key */
    exit(0);
  }
}


void
init()
{
  glPointSize(3); 
  glShadeModel (GL_FLAT); 
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);    
  gluPerspective(45,1.0,10.0,200.0);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);
  glLineWidth(2);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  glutInit(&argc,argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
  glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
  glutInitWindowSize(110*3, 110*3);
  glutCreateWindow("draw circle");
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutKeyboardFunc(keyb);
  init();
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: thanks for you'r answer.. look at my code i have 5 ring look like olympic rings when i use youre code just 1 circle rotate..

Comment: @hesam It's only one ring because the glTranslate calls were not relative. I fixed it. Try again it works now as you wanted.

Comment: whoplisp » thank for you'r helpful example

Comment: @hesam salehnamadi If you have any further questions just ask.

Comment: > whoplisp : 1 question :D .. how can i reduce speed of rotation?

Comment: @hesam salehnamadi To increase the speed by a factor of two you can change the line count++; into count=count+2; You may also want to make sure that the framerate limited to the vertical refresh rate of your screen. You can either enable sync to vblank in your graphics card driver, then the program will stop execution whenever you call glutSwapBuffers until a new frame must be generated (this looks best). Alternatively you can just put a call to usleep to wait for 16ms. To decrease the speed you will have to change the type of count to float and use count=count+0.1;